# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory index.html Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a problem when trying to redirect routes from node.js to react router.

```
 app.get('*', (req,res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '../client/build/index.html'));
    });html
```

My browser says:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/node/app../client/build/index.html'
```

[image: Here's printscreen of my directories]

Btw, what __dirname does?

Comment: The path is missing a slash after `app`, before `../client`. As for `__dirname`, Google it.

Comment: do you mean? /../client/build/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use something like this...

> path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'client/build/index.html')

```
**Like Explained here**
path.resolve('wwwroot', 'static_files/png/', '../gif/image.gif');
{
 if the current working directory is /home/myself/node,
 this returns '/home/myself/node/wwwroot/static_files/gif/image.gif'
}
```

Comment: What if we are creating index.html on the fly using HTMLWebPack plugin? The file is basically on the server so I get same error unfortunately.  How can I find the path of directory in terms of server?